# Effectively using KMP with array to count word frequency count

Tags: c++, c

I want to count word frequency from a article.

My thought is first create a struct array

```
 struct{
       char[WORD_SIZE]
 }data[MAX_WORD_NUMBER];
```

and then read each character then determine by

```
isalpha();
```

and then convert to lowercase by

```
tolower();
```

then store a word to each struct.

then make failure function for every word,

then test each word by call it.

1.But I don't know how to count the frequency due to repetition has caused.

(I thought I can compare it each time when I read and insert a word, but it is so ineffective, is there a more efficient way?)

2.I think that my method call function too many time.

How can I use KMP more effectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are programming in C or C++? You tagged your question with both.

Assuming you are using C++ then you are going to do much better with `std::map` to count your words. Something like this

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<std::string, int> data;

std::string word;

data[word] = 0; // set word count to zero
data[word]++; // increment word count

// print out all the word counts
for (std::map<std::string, int>::iterator i = data.begin();
  i != data.end(); ++i)
{
  cout << "word " << i->first << " occurs " << i->second << "times\n";
}
```

This task will be **so** much easier if you choose the right tools for the job. Of course if you are programming in C then none of this is going to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to do this in C, extend your structure like so:

```
struct {
    char[WORD_SIZE];
    int count;
} data[MAX_WORD_NUMBER];
```

And then whenever you store a new word in this array of structures also set the respective `count` to 0.

Then if you find that a word is already in the array, increment the respective `count`.

At the end of the program print the counts.